# How to Protect Angular CLI Assets with canActivate

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-cli

Right now anyone can access my `assets` by doing `http://localhost:4200/assets/filename.pdf` even when the user is not logged in. How can I protect my `assets` by using `canActivate`?

Something like this would be ideal: `{ path: 'assets/*', canActivate: [LoginService] },`

Thanks.

Comment: I hope, we can't do it. canActive is for routing purpose. https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/18/guards-in-angular-2.html

Answer (score 1):

No. You want to use use server-side authentication and authorization to protect file access.

Always assume anyone can access assets in your Angular application.

Comment: So you would recommend me moving assets that shouldn't be accessible to logged out users outside the `assets` folder and use something like `node.js` to protect their access?

Comment: @ilovelamp Yes. Use `node.js` or any other server side technology to protect any files or records that users should be authorized to access.

Comment: @Martin, what about if I want to forbid access to the http://localhost:4200/assets/ and see all my website assets, should I set that specific path and redirects to a custom page?

Answer (score 1):

You want to authenticate via the backend, but you also want to set up your routing in Angular using canActivate and something like AuthGuard so that the only initial route that can be accessed is the login route/component. That way no other assets/routes are available until after login authentication has happened.